# How does Lokalise.co library override text attribute of TextView

Tags: android, android-resources

I'm trying to write my own localization library.
I'm trying to figure out how to override all the calls to string assets.

I've figured out I can have a ContextWrapper like:

```
class MyConextWrapper(context: Context?) : ContextWrapper(context) {
private val _baseResources = context?.resources
private var customResources : Resources? = null

override fun getResources(): Resources {
    if (customResources == null) {
        customResources = MyRes(_baseResources?.assets, _baseResources?.displayMetrics, _baseResources?.configuration)
    }
    return customResources!!
}


}

class MyRes : Resources {
constructor(assets: AssetManager?, metrics: DisplayMetrics?, config: Configuration?) : super(assets, metrics, config)

override fun getString(id: Int): String {
    return super.getString(id)
}

override fun getString(id: Int, vararg formatArgs: Any?): String {
    return super.getString(id, *formatArgs)
}

override fun getText(id: Int): CharSequence {
    return super.getText(id)
}

override fun getText(id: Int, def: CharSequence?): CharSequence {
    return super.getText(id, def)
}
}
```

And then override in my activity like

```
override fun attachBaseContext(newBase: Context?) {
    super.attachBaseContext(MyConextWrapper(newBase))
}
```

Now all the calls to getString(R.String.*) will go through my code

But how do I override seamlessly things like

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/headlineTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/string_id"/>
```

How can I override the string that comes out of this string_id asset?

When debugging how TextView works I see that it gets the string from `TypedArray` which in turn takes it directly from `assetManager` and this class is final so I cannot override it in my ContextWrapper.

My question is how can I modify this behavior like https://lokalise.co/ say they do

Comment: Why is the Android translation not a good fit?

Comment: I want to be able to add and modify content without having to release a new version of my app.

Comment: Do you only want to modify existing texts or you want to create new screena from scratch?

Comment: I want that all methods of getting a string from resources (resources.getString, applicationContext.getString etc.) will go through my code so I can decide the value at runtime. So this integration is future proof and there's no need to change the way Android developers work

Answer (score -1):

Override the getString function to do whatever you want.  Their code is going to call getString, passing in the id of the string they want.  You can then return any String you wish.

Comment: I'm trying to achieve this without integrating Lokalise.co or similar, but rather do it completely in house. From what I see they create a custom LayoutInflater and pass a Factory2 to get callbacks on OnViewCreated and modify the view from there

Comment: That seems unnecessary.  Just use LayoutInflater.from(context) passing in the contextwrapper here.  No need to use the onViewCreated.

Comment: I don't call LayoutInflater.from. It's done from within the activity creation